# Laravel Orderby not working inside Eloquent whereHas relationship?

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Please have look on below code.

```
 $serviceNew = CompletedService::selectRaw('gallons_collected as total,account_id,id,service_provider_id,service_id,service_date')
            ->where("service_id", '1')->where('service_provider_id', $service_privider_id)->whereMonth('service_date', $month)->whereYear('service_date', $year)
            ->with('account')
            ->whereHas('account', function($qs) {
                $qs->orderBy('restaurant_name', 'DESC');
            })
            ->get();
```

I have multiple records in "CompletedService" and there is one parent id account_id which in account table. and i made with on account.

Already ASC and DESC tried.

Try to order by in whereHas but it's not affect on any records.
Below is model relationship.

```
 public function account() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Account', 'id', 'account_id');
}
```

i don't need to orderby in model because i used this relation in multiple time and need only order by in this single query.

**And one completed service records relations have only one account.
So basically i need to sort completed service records on the account field.**

Output
[image]

Tables

**CompletedService**

```
|id| account_id|service_id|service_provider_id|gallons_collected|service_date
|1 | 2         | 1        | 9                 | 50              | 2017-08-29
```

**Accounts**

```
| id | restaurant_name|
```

**Every help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use alternate solution for this. First you need to fetch your data/collection and then need to apply order by.

Laravel provides some functions, using that you can sort your collection.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sortby

Use `sortByDesc` (for descending). So here is your code :

```
$serviceNew = CompletedService::selectRaw('gallons_collected as total,account_id,id,service_provider_id,service_id,service_date')
            ->where("service_id", '1')->where('service_provider_id', $service_privider_id)->whereMonth('service_date', $month)->whereYear('service_date', $year)
            ->with('account')
            ->whereHas('account')
            ->get()
            ->sortByDesc('account.restaurant_name');
```

Comment: is "sortByDesc" work with laravel pagination?

Answer (score 3):

`orderBy()` has no effect in a `whereHas()` query; you need to move the `orderBy()` logic to a `with()` statement:

```
$serviceNew = CompletedService::selectRaw('gallons_collected as total,account_id,id,service_provider_id,service_id,service_date')
  ->where("service_id", '1')
  ->where('service_provider_id', $service_privider_id)
  ->whereMonth('service_date', $month)
  ->whereYear('service_date', $year)
  ->with(['account' => function($qs){
    $qs->orderBy('restaurant_name', 'DESC');
  })->has('account')->get();
```

Edit: The above is sorting each `CompletedService`'s `Account` record by `restaurant_name`, which doesn't accomplish anything. To sort all `CompletedService` models by their `Account`'s `restaurant_name` column, you'll need a `join()` clause:

```
$newService = CompletedService::selectRaw('gallons_collected as total,account_id,id,service_provider_id,service_id,service_date')
->where('service_id', '1')
->where('service_provider_id', $service_privider_id)
->whereMonth('service_date', $month)
->whereYear('service_date', $year)
->join('accounts', 'accounts.id', '=', 'completed_services.account_id')
->orderBy('accounts.restaurant_name');
```

You shouldn't need the `with()` clause anymore, but using the `has()` ensures you don't get `null` values if there's no relationship.

Comment: Are you trying to order the `Account` or the `CompletedService` model? Can you share the code that outputs these results?

Comment: Nothing new in this code above i mention that's only just date is for current month and year.. and service_provider_id is some number i.e "9"

Comment: then this loop for print
foreach ($serviceNew as $key => $value) {
            $total = $total + $value->total;
            echo $value->account->restaurant_name . '<br>';
        }

Comment: So it likely _is_ sorting each `Account` properly, but since you're looping over `$serviceNew`, it'll only sort them in scope of each `$value`; if you want to get a sorted list of all `Account` models, you'll have to loop over them, pul them into a collection, then run the `sortBy()` method on those. That or use a different query.

Comment: One completed service have one account id. that related records come form accounts table. and that records fetch in relationship. so every completed service have only one accounts name. i need to sort on those relationship. to whole completed service records.

Comment: Right, so you can either `orderBy()` on the `account_id` key, which will give you results based on an invisible value, or you need to add a `join()` clause to your query and sort on that. I'll provide an update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153190/discussion-between-yagnik-detroja-and-tim-lewis).

Answer (score 1):

`whereHas()` used to limit your results based on the existence of a relationship.

See : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Use the below code to add consraint in relationship :

```
$serviceNew = CompletedService::selectRaw('gallons_collected as total,account_id,id,service_provider_id,service_id,service_date')
        ->where("service_id", '1')->where('service_provider_id', $service_privider_id)->whereMonth('service_date', $month)->whereYear('service_date', $year)
        ->with(['account' => function($qs) {
            $qs->orderBy('restaurant_name', 'DESC'); 
        }])->get();
```

See : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: this suggestion show an error with strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Check answer update and see last mentioned link for more details.

Comment: Do have actually idea about Laravel or just posted answer for the reputation. I need answer for particular this and find a mistake from the code. that's why i am posted here. otherwise i am also able to find solution from R&D

Comment: If you check difference between `whereHas()` and `with()` methods in laravel documentation you can find your answer. I do not think reading a few lines takes a lot of time.