# WhereHas not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables in my db. 
1. Problem table, every problem has some conversation 
2. conversation table - every conversation has messages 
3. Message table

I am calling a query on conversation table

```
$answerQuery = \App\Models\TB_Conversation::withCount('hasManyMessages')
    ->with(['hasManyMessages', 'hasManyMessages.createdBy', 'hasManyMessages.reply_of_message_id'])
    ->where('TB_Xolution_Problem_id', '=', $request->problem_id)
    ->whereHas('hasManyMessages', function ($query) {
        $query->where('status_enum', '=', ENUM_STATUS_CODE_ACTIVE)
            ->orderBy('created_on', 'DESC');
    })->where(function ($query) use ($userId) {
        $query->where('initiated_user_id', '=', $userId)
            ->orwhere('receiver_user_id', '=', $userId);
    })->get();
```

I want all the messages of the conversations in descending order but my query is failing because of whereHas clause. What am I doing wrong, my conversation has messages.

Edit_1 - I have tried orderBy('created_on','desc') but I am still not getting any results.

Comment: What error you have got?

Comment: check in table created_on field available

Comment: You missed to use orderBy. I believe it should be like this: ->whereHas('hasManyMessages',function ($query){
                $query->where('status_enum','=',ENUM_STATUS_CODE_ACTIVE)
                    ->orderBy('created_on','DESC');

Comment: I am not getting any error, I am getting empty array in response

Comment: I have created_on field in table as timestamp

Comment: I tried with orderBy but I am still not getting any results @AbdullahAlShakib

Comment: @LovepreetSingh

Comment: can you include code for `hasManyMessages` relation?

Comment: @Wreigh public function hasManyMessages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\TB_Message', 'TB_Conversation_id', 'id');
    }

Comment: Might be a problem with orwhere, i've had problems with eloquent generating the wrong parenthesis in the past. Have you tried inspecting the sql code?

Comment: what does this `where` do? `where('created_on', 'DESC')`. Seems a mistake.

Comment: @Wreigh, I have changed it, I am using orderBy there but still getting no response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Laravel Orderby not working inside Eloquent whereHas relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940755/laravel-orderby-not-working-inside-eloquent-wherehas-relationship)
This thread helps me in understanding that orderBy will not work inside whereHas so I have to use with function.